# Trouble creating google gauge chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, gauge

I am having some issues dynamically creating code for Google Gauge visualization. My main problem is that I am trying to build the javascript based on what is returned in some JSON to build multiple gauge panels for a temp monitoring dashboard. Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //Get php data about sensor into json array for javasript processing
        var gauges = <?php echo json_encode($sensor_data);?>;

        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["gauge"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        for (var i = 0, len = gauges.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var gauge = gauges[i];
            var currentTemp = gauge.value;
            var chartID = "chart_div_" + gauge.sensor_id;
            var gMin = gauge.config_min_temp;
            var gMax = gauge.config_max_temp;
            var lLimit = gauge.limits_low;
            var hLimit = gauge.limits_high;

            //calculate major tick increments
            var increment = (parseFloat(gMax) - parseFloat(gMin))/4;
            var tick0 = gMin;
            var tick1 = parseFloat(gMin) + parseFloat(increment);
            var tick2 = parseFloat(tick1) + parseFloat(increment);
            var tick3 = parseFloat(tick2) + parseFloat(increment);
            var tick4 = gMax; 

            var Ticks = [tick0, tick1, tick2, tick3, tick4];

            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Label', 'Value'],
                    ['Temp', 0]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    width: 220, height: 220,
                    redFrom: hLimit, redTo: gMax,
                    yellowFrom: gMin, yellowTo: lLimit,
                    greenFrom:  gMin, greenTo: gMax,
                    minorTicks: 5,
                    majorTicks: Ticks,
                    min: gMin,
                    max: gMax,
                    redColor: '#ff0000',
                    yellowColor: '#ff0000',
                    greenColor: '#00cc00'
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById(chartID));
                data.setValue(0, 1, currentTemp);
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

My issue is that I cannot create an array of the data object. I need to reference that object inside the for loop. I have googled this issue until I am at my wits end and cannot come up with a good way to do this. I am wide open for suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as-is will create a single `drawChart` function and then overwrite it, which I am fairly certain is not your intention.  This code will loop over your `gauges` array and draw a Gauge for each element in the array:

```
function drawChart() {
    for (var i = 0, len = gauges.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var gauge = gauges[i];
        var currentTemp = gauge.value;
        var chartID = "chart_div_" + gauge.sensor_id;
        var gMin = gauge.config_min_temp;
        var gMax = gauge.config_max_temp;
        var lLimit = gauge.limits_low;
        var hLimit = gauge.limits_high;

        //calculate major tick increments
        var increment = (parseFloat(gMax) - parseFloat(gMin))/4;
        var tick0 = gMin;
        var tick1 = parseFloat(gMin) + parseFloat(increment);
        var tick2 = parseFloat(tick1) + parseFloat(increment);
        var tick3 = parseFloat(tick2) + parseFloat(increment);
        var tick4 = gMax; 

        var Ticks = [tick0, tick1, tick2, tick3, tick4];

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Label', 'Value'],
            ['Temp', currentTemp]
        ]);

        var options = {
            width: 220, height: 220,
            redFrom: hLimit, redTo: gMax,
            yellowFrom: gMin, yellowTo: lLimit,
            greenFrom:  gMin, greenTo: gMax,
            minorTicks: 5,
            majorTicks: Ticks,
            min: gMin,
            max: gMax,
            redColor: '#ff0000',
            yellowColor: '#ff0000',
            greenColor: '#00cc00'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById(chartID));
        data.setValue(0, 1, currentTemp);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

Is that what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: That is what I am trying to accomplish. I figured out my problem yesterday afternoon and the solution was functionally the same as what you provided. I had a misunderstanding about how exactly the chart was being drawn. Thanks so much for your help.